# How to convert json from one format to another

Tags: c#, json

I have a control that expects JSON in a particular format.  I have a service that spits out JSON in a different format.  What's the best way to convert the JSON to the expected format? C#, jQuery?  I think I'd prefer to do it server-side.

Comment: From what format to what format exactly? It's not that hard I guess, decode this JSON to a native object and then alter that and encode it to JSON again.

Comment: Actually I've had to change direction due to double-hop issue.  Now I'm creating a WCF service that serializes the objcets for me.  However I'm hitting other issues which i may have to ask in a different thread ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C# you can use System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer to parse your JSON string to an object or IDictionary.

[MSDN: JavaScriptSerializer Class (System.Web.Script.Serialization)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

With that object you could do anything you like, change values or maybe just parse it back to something like XML.